# looping in list while changing it

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I want to loop through the original entries of a list even though it gets updated.

```
itterable = copy.deepcopy(dict[node].adjacent_nodes)
for i in itterable:

    new_node = create_node(i)
    dict[node].adjacent_nodes.append(new_node)
    dict[node].adjacent_nodes.remove(i)
```

I want my `dict[node].adjacent_nodes` to be updated only the number of times as there are elements in `dict[node].adjacent_nodes` initially. This does not happen. What am I missing?

__

For example if `dict[node].adjacent_nodes = [1,2]` initially. Then my for loop should run 2 times. Each time creating a new_node and adding to `dict[node].adjacent_nodes`. At the end the for loop should terminate with `dict[node].adjacent_nodes = [create_node(1), create_node(2)]`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a full working example of the problem with output vs expected output, so I'll guess some possible issues:

1. A recursive loop can occur in the creation of this compound node object - in the `create_node()` part or in the `copy.deepcopy()` (complex objects that include a direct or indirect reference to self).
2. While doing the `copy.deepcopy()` you might copy some data that is later causing a problem as it is not meant to be copied (e.g. the global state of the graph etc.).
3. `create_node()` affects the `itterable` or the `adjacent_nodes` structures.
4. The `append` or `remove` do not behave the way you expect them to in your data struct.

Hope some of it helps you.